# SQLite Delete from New Table data that exists in old table

Tags: sqlite, where-clause, sql-delete, intersect

I get daily update files of progress on a project that have no date field. I have added a date column to the first Table and imported the 1st and 2nd tables into SQLIte.  Now I want to delete from the 2nd table, data that already exists in the 1st table so that I can add a new date to the 2nd table and then insert the 2nd table into the 1st table.  The problem I am having is with the delete from 2nd table part.  Column4 data Intersects in both Tables.

I tried the following SQL statement, but it deletes all the rows from Table2:

DELETE from Table2 WHERE exists (SELECT Col4 from Table1 INTERSECT SELECT Col4 from Table2);

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exists checks the existence of rows in your subquery. Your problem will be solved by using "not in" statement

```
DELETE from Table2 WHERE Col4 not in (SELECT Col4 from Table1 INTERSECT SELECT Col4 from Table2);
```